# Python logger filter not work in msg %s variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter, yaml

Hi i am using in python logging, and i want replace passwords from console and debug file using filters. but it works only in some cases

```
import logging
import logging.config
from collections import defaultdict

class AwesomeFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        if 'password' in rec:
            return "here is password, i hide this line"
        else:
            return 1

LOG_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'filters': {
        'file_filter': {
            '()': AwesomeFilter,
        },
    },
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,


    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'filters': ['file_filter'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_CONFIG)
```

this works, if i wrote

log.info("line with my super password")  - here it works, and replace whole line

BUT if i want use

log.info ("returned line is %s") and in %s is string "here is password" filter ignore this line, because of :

`<LogRecord: PGSQLDatabaseConnection, 20, dluznici.py, 172, "returned line is: %s">`

so, here isnt word "password" ... how to check passwords in %s ?

maybe i must define filters here too ?

```
class PGSQLDatabase:
    def __init__(self, conn_params, session_params):
        self.log = logging.getLogger('PGSQLDatabaseConnection')
        self.filter = ????????????
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i can search thru args in filter :)